# Is a split button valid without proper visual grouping

Tags: buttons

[Split button](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/split-buttons/) is basically a button with a default action and several other actions which are shown in a drop-down menu.

While there's no doubt in how it functions, the issue is with how the default-action and more-actions icon should be highlighted in UI.

I have created basic variations of split buttons in below pen.

https://codepen.io/paulj05hua/full/PooayrP

-- edit -- Adding GIF ..

[image: split-button-cases]

In the above, both styles 1 & 2 are properly highlighted as a single group. But with style 3 user might mistake the more-actions arrow as separate button.

So the question is **whether style 3 is valid or not** ?

PS:

- style 3 is used by Gmail in the mail list panel for selecting emails

  [image: gmail-split-button-usage]

  If this is considered **valid**, kindly state the reason.
- There's no mention of this type of component in material design (
  material.io )

Comment: Hi @paulj05hua, thanks for your contribution to UXSE. It is a really interesting question about a common design pattern for a UI component, and hopefully there will be some good answers.

Comment: I feel like there is no real argument for style 3 that would outweigh the usability aspect of the first two. Especially with something so little as a hover effect.

Comment: @MichaelLai Thanks !

Comment: @Big_Chair Yes. That's what I was thought too. But posted here to get clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The best and the worst thing about UX is that there are no laws

There are guidelines, best-practices, widely-accepted patterns and certain broadly defined rules. But no unbreakable laws.

Split-buttons, by definition, should be styled as a group and at the same time, be properly separated. Styles 1 and 2 clearly indicate to the user that the dropdown next to "Reply" is related to it.

---

*But now, to answer your question*... **Style 3**, unfortunately, is not invalid. 
**IT'S NOT RECOMMENDED**, but it is not invalid.

I like to keep mentioning this to many of my colleagues and to the people in the community that, *"just because a big, famous company did something, doesn't mean it's right"*. So, always try to make your design as accessible as possible and if there's a conflict, A/B test with a group of users

Comment: +1 It would be nice sometimes if there were laws... then we can penalize people for bad design :D

Comment: I'm choosing this as the answer, for now. To add to this, I agree with @Pete & Karthi 's answers on using spacing to reduce the confusion. However, while considering cognitive-load of a typical user, I guess styles 1 & 2 greatly reduces the load here, and style 3 only increases it. User will at least think twice or thrice before actually clicking the drop-down button, as it shows hover-highlight separate from the default action button, and user might initially think those are two different actions.

Answer (score 2):

I think it stands to reason that it must be "valid", otherwise Google wouldn't be doing it. I think that the only thing you need to look out for is the spacing - in the case of the Gmail screenshot you posted, note how close the drop-down arrow is to the checkbox that it relates to, and note how the space between the drop-down arrow and the next button (refresh) is about as wide as the drop-down arrow button itself. This establishes a very clear visual cue that the drop-down arrow button relates to the checkbox.

In the attached screenshot, I've closed up the space between the buttons, and you can see how the purpose of the drop-down arrow starts to become ambiguous.

[image: mockup of gmail interface with whitespace between buttons reduced]

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, _just because a big, famous company did something, doesn't mean it's right_.

Answer (score 0):

> whether style 3 is valid or not

Yes, it **could be considered valid**,

When the actions inside dropdown are on a similar level to "Reply". 
For Ex: Forward and Reply All,

---

**It goes invalid** when the dropdown values are just a dependent of the primary value For Ex: Reply Preferences.

This is because highlighting *dependent actions* alongside a primary action isn't as important as highlighting actions of a *similar level*.

However, for both cases, it is important that the dropdown is in close proximity to its primary action (Reply) so it is obvious that the actions are intentionally grouped together